# The best way for an app

Tags: database, swift, viewcontroller, levels

I am making an app on iOS with a `ViewController` where the user can see a picture and has to find an object to pass the level.

When the level is complete, I want to show a different picture with different solution, and in this point I have thought two different ways:

1. A new `ViewController` with the second level, or
2. In the same `ViewController` showing a new picture with a new solution.

How could I make this option? Is it possible?

I would like to make something like a data base with a index with the different pictures and their different solutions.

Comment: No need to say 'thankyou' in posts. You can create numbered lists by having 1. as the leading list type. You can use ` for code snippets around words, too.

Comment: I think It is possible with an array too.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking 'what is the best way' posts are closed on StackOverflow. However, if you are creating a game with different levels then you'll generally use one `ViewController` and then simply load in different data, rather than having one `ViewController` per level -- the only time you'd do that is if the levels work in very different ways (for example, one is a find-the-puzzle and another level is a racing game)